# Shipley's d separation test in piecewise structural equation model

Tags: r, mixed-model, structural-equation-modeling, discriminant-analysis, d-separation

I have created a piecewise structural equation model for when the temperature exceeds 0 degrees Celsius, and how that relates to the green up day across Northern Europe.
I have standardised all data

```
library(readr)
library(nlme)
library(piecewiseSEM)

df = read_csv("C:/Users/data.csv")
df = df %>% mutate_at(c('greenupday', 'tempday', 'treespecies', 'prePrecip', 'preRH', 'preTEMP', 'preEvap', 'preWS','postPrecip','postRH','postTEMP', 'postEvap', 'postWS'), ~(scale(.) %>% as.vector))

#Piecewise SEM
SEMmodel.mixed <- psem(lme(tempday ~ prePrecip+preTEMP, data = df, random = ~1+prePrecip+preTEMP|COUNTRY,
                     method = 'ML', control = lmeControl(opt = "optim", msMaxIter=1000, maxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000)),
                  lme(greenupday ~ tempday+treespecies+postPrecip+postRH+postTEMP+postEvap+postWS, data = df,
                     random = ~1+greenupday ~ tempday+treespecies+postPrecip+postRH+postTEMP+postEvap+postWS|COUNTRY, method = 'ML',
                     control = lmeControl(opt = "optim", msMaxIter=1000, maxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000)),
                  lme(postEvap ~ tempday, data = df, random = ~1+tempday|COUNTRY, method = 'ML',
                     control = lmeControl(opt = "optim", msMaxIter=1000, maxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000)),
                  lme(postPrecip ~ tempday, data = df, random = ~1+tempday|COUNTRY, method = 'ML',
                     control = lmeControl(opt = "optim", msMaxIter=1000, maxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000)),
                  prePrecip%~~% preTEMP)
```

I have from previous analyses, including variance partitioning and bi-variate analysis, determined these are the variables that may tell us something about why the day in which temperature > 0 degree Celsius (`tempday`) occurs when it does, and how the other variables influence the green up day (`greenupday`).
I use a linear mixed effect model since I am working across Northern Europe and set the `COUNTRY` variable as random effect.

When I perform the `psem`, I do get a summary in which the Fisher's C statistic is < 0.05 but at the same time **no** error like

```
## Error: 
## Non-linearities detected in the basis set where P-values are not symmetrical. 
## This can bias the outcome of the tests of directed separation.
```

The summary basically looks like this

```
dSep(SEMmodel.mixed, conserve = T)

              Independ.Claim Test.Type   DF Crit.Value P.Value    
 greenupday ~ prePrecip + ...       coef 1065     6.4556  0.0000 ***
    postEvap ~ prePRsum + ...       coef 1070    -3.0650  0.0022  **
    postTEMP ~ prePRsum + ...       coef 1070    -7.3391  0.0000 ***
   greenupday ~ preTEMP + ...       coef 1065     2.5402  0.0111   *
     postEvap ~ preTEMP + ...       coef 1070    -3.1977  0.0014  **
     postTEMP ~ preTEMP + ...       coef 1070    15.0704  0.0000 ***
   tempday ~ postPrecip + ...       coef 1069     0.8361  0.4031    
  postEvap ~ postPrecip + ...       coef 1070   -15.3408  0.0000 ***
  postTEMP ~ postPrecip + ...       coef 1070   -27.7484  0.0000 ***
       tempday ~ postRH + ...       coef 1069    -7.8886  0.0000 ***
      postEvap ~ postRH + ...       coef 1070   -36.3077  0.0000 ***
      postTEMP ~ postRH + ...       coef 1070   -47.1516  0.0000 ***
     tempday ~ postTEMP + ...       coef 1069     5.6392  0.0000 ***
    postEvap ~ postTEMP + ...       coef 1070    23.1458  0.0000 ***
 treespecies ~ postTEMP + ...       coef 1070    41.8395  0.0000 ***
 treespecies ~ postEvap + ...       coef 1070    30.1862  0.0000 ***

Global goodness-of-fit:

  Fisher's C = 978.927 with P-value = 0 and on 32 degrees of freedom
```

It seems from the d-separation test that the model wants more input between response variables, but I do not believe that should be the case.

1. Can I somehow tell the model to not account for this?
2. As I do not get any error, can I ignore the Fisher's C test?

Here is [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nmxYT0pLdv9duhCOZ18DRObH017EX88n/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113272805036957161800&rtpof=true&sd=true)